# Calling a jQuery plugin from another jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML page that loads both the `CSS` and `JS` files for two plugins. I need to call `plugin1`'s function from within `plugin2`'s JS file.

Below is part of the plugin (`plugin2`), specifically the event that needs to fire the function from the other plugin (near the end).

```
onOk      : function () {
    var pre, element;
    pre = element = this.element;

    if (this.insertMode) {
        if (shighlighter.getTag() !== 'pre') {
            element = this.element.getChild(0);
        }
    }
    else {
        pre = element.getAscendant('pre', true);
    }

    this.commitContent(element);

    shighlighter.setCls(pre.getAttribute("data-pbcklang") + " " + editor.settings.cls);

    element.setAttribute('class', shighlighter.getCls());

    if (this.insertMode) {
        editor.insertElement(pre);

        /* START: HERE IS THE FUNCTION I NEED TO CALL FROM THE OTHER PLUGIN. */

        $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
            hljs.highlightBlock(block);
        });

        /* END: HERE IS THE FUNCTION I NEED TO CALL FROM THE OTHER PLUGIN. */
    }
}
```

The above doesn't work, so I was wondering how I can change that.

Thanks.

Comment: Show how `hljs` is defined - it may be the issue of scope. Also other variables, such as `shighlighter` and `editor`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by defined. I don't know how to "define" it within another plugin's file.

Comment: you are calling/using `shighlighter.setCls`, `editor.settings`, `hljs.highlightBlock` - what are `shighlighter`, `editor`, `hljs`?

Comment: `shlighter` and `editor` are used within that plugin (they have nothing to do with `hljs`). `hljs` is the other plugin I'm trying to call.

Comment: Again, somewhere you must have code such as `var hljs;` or `var hljs = ...;` or `hljs = ...;`. Show it.

Comment: I don't. That's why I said I don't know how to define another plugin like that.

Comment: Let me slightly rephrase - somewhere `plugin1` must have code such as ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the plugins in the correct order. The global variable hljs must be defined when used, so it should suffice to put the script tag for plugin1 (hljs) before the script tag for plugin2.